# how to insert svg image instead of dots in slick-dots?

Tags: javascript

```
Index.html:

 <div class="carousel">
                <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_1"><br><span>John Smith</span><br><p>Marketing Director at XYZ Corp</p></div>
                <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_2"><br><span>John Smith</span><br><p>Marketing Director at XYZ Corp</p></div>
                <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_3"><br><span>John Smith</span><br><p>Marketing Director at XYZ Corp</p></div>
                <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_3"><br><span>John Smith</span><br><p>Marketing Director at XYZ Corp</p></div>
                <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_3"><br><span>John Smith</span><br><p>Marketing Director at XYZ Corp</p></div>
  </div>
```

```
SCSS:

// other code

 .slick-dots{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 124px;
    }
    .slick-dots li button {
        content: url('../../icons/Vector.svg');
        font-size: 0;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        border: none;
        margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
    }
```

```
index.js:

const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
    const prevArrow = '<button type="button"  class="slick-prev"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M22 13.5C22.8284 13.5 23.5 12.8284 23.5 12C23.5 11.1716 22.8284 10.5 22 10.5L22 13.5ZM0.939341 10.9393C0.353554 11.5251 0.353554 12.4749 0.93934 13.0607L10.4853 22.6066C11.0711 23.1924 12.0208 23.1924 12.6066 22.6066C13.1924 22.0208 13.1924 21.0711 12.6066 20.4853L4.12132 12L12.6066 3.51472C13.1924 2.92893 13.1924 1.97918 12.6066 1.3934C12.0208 0.807611 11.0711 0.807611 10.4853 1.3934L0.939341 10.9393ZM22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5Z" fill=""/></svg></button>';
    const nextArrow = '<button type="button"  class="slick-next"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10.5C1.17157 10.5 0.5 11.1716 0.5 12C0.5 12.8284 1.17157 13.5 2 13.5L2 10.5ZM23.0607 13.0607C23.6464 12.4749 23.6464 11.5251 23.0607 10.9393L13.5147 1.3934C12.9289 0.807613 11.9792 0.807613 11.3934 1.3934C10.8076 1.97919 10.8076 2.92893 11.3934 3.51472L19.8787 12L11.3934 20.4853C10.8076 21.0711 10.8076 22.0208 11.3934 22.6066C11.9792 23.1924 12.9289 23.1924 13.5147 22.6066L23.0607 13.0607ZM2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5Z" fill=""/></svg></button>';

    const settings = {
        speed: 1000,
        // adaptiveHeight: true,
        infinite: false,
        dots: true,
        slidesToShow: 2.99,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        prevArrow: prevArrow,
        nextArrow: nextArrow,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 767,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1.99,
                    dots: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 575,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    dots: false
                }
            }
        ]
    };

   
    
    if (carousel) {
        $('.carousel').slick(settings)
        
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrViO.png)

I need to have an svg image instead of toggle points.

I tried to do as shown in the scss file, but it did not help I also need this svg image to be able to style it when the slides are flipped

There was a suggestion to do this: change the file slick-theme.css in this file all the styles related to the Slick slider are registered.
But it's better not to do this, these are the styles of the library itself, and if you edit them, you can lose all styles when switching to a new version of the library. In the case of slick , there will be no updates (the slider is obviously dead, the last update was in 2017, and there are better options), nevertheless this is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

```
I managed . Here is the solution to this problem:

//other code..
.slick-dots li button {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        border: none;
        margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
        background: transparent;
        display: block;
        &:before{
            content: url('../../icons/Vector.svg');                                              
        }
        
    }
```